# Session.Start called on every request when fired

Tags: asp.net, session, sessionid

I've got a "works on my machine" situation.

I have a website where I'm passing session values from one page to another using

```
Session["foo"] = 'blah';
```

and on page2

```
var foo = Session["foo"];
```

foo doesn't exist on page2.

When tracing the page I've found it was using a different sessionid to the original page. When putting a breakpoint on Session_start it looks like for each request the page is starting a new session.

This does not occur on my machine... and thoughts on what I can do to solve on other machines?

- The SessionState is InProc
- Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx are both
  part of the same website and
- Privacy
  is set to accept all cookies on the
  target machine.

**EDIT:** Difference between running on my machine and target is that I am using http://localhost/blah locally and http://XX_0001/blah from the other client where XX_0001 is my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I have found the solution:

It looks like the _ in my machine name is causing the issue. Seems that hostnames do not allow underscores: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to check to see if cookies are enabled on the computer that is having the problem. Does it work in other browsers etc?

If you're changing the url as well, ensure that you're still on the same site because different sites will use different cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the string indexing Session was case sensitive. You've got "foo" and "Foo". Is that a typo?

Otherwise, cookies would be my guess as well.